# Problems with Object-C++ and Framework

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, cocos2d-iphone, box2d, iphone-wax

I have this project that needs to integrate Box2D, Cocos2d-iPhone and iPhone wax.
At first I put cocos2d-iphone and box2d together, and it gives me this error message:

```
    fatal error: 'cassert' file not found
    #include <cassert>
             ^
```

And I search and found out it's because box2d is written in c++, and you have to set all source files referring to box2d to *.mm, so apple compiler can compile it as object-c++.

So I just changed every source files into *.mm and it worked.

And then I tried to get iPhone wax into it.
iPhone wax is written in object-c and c. And they provide a wax.framework. So I download it and drag it into my project's frameworks zone. And it gives me this error:

```
     "__Z9wax_startPcPFiP9lua_StateEz", referenced from:
          _main in main_old.o
    ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

so I search again and I find out it's because of the expected library does not exist.
And I check list by list and I am pretty sure every setting is correct and I could not find the problem.

So I did some test.
I create a new and sample project from one of those templates, and I put iPhone wax into it and it works fine.
And then I changed the main.m file into main.mm and it gives the error just like above.

So how do I fix this?
Is this because object-C++ can't import a object-c and c framework?
Should I just recreate the framework and change all their names to *.mm?
Or did I do wrong when I changed my source files into *.mm and there should be a better way of solving it?

Comment: Thanks for the posted answers.Actually the problem is caused by C++ trying to call C function. I am just obsessed with that whole Object-C++ thing and I forgot about it. Just put extern C where wax is imported and everything is fixed.
Thanks again for the help.

Comment: I figured out the problem just several minutes after I posted this question. 
Is it how StackOverFlow works? You post a question and then you find out the answer yourself. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That function is actually a function called `wax_start()`.  All the other crap is name mangling added by the C++ compiler.  This is needed to support overloading i.e. the other crap encodes the parameter and return types of `wax_start()`.  The easiest way to fix this is to tell the C++ compiler that everything in that header is pure C e.g.

```
extern "C"
{
 #import "Wax/whatever.h"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use main.mm but stick with main.m. No need to rename main.m for Box2D. This works because you typically don't include/import any Box2D (C++) headers in main.m.

If you add Box2D (C++) header files to your prefix header, make sure they're only included in C++ (Objective-C++) files like so:

```
// C++ header files
#ifdef __cplusplus
#import "Box2D.h"
#endif // __cplusplus
```